# Post request not working because of error

Tags: javascript

```
send()
      function send() {

        var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "http://thelink.com");

      var params = {
        "gameVersion": "1",
        "binaryVersion": "1",
      }

      request.send(params);
        console.log(request.response);
    }
```

So whenever I try to make this post request I keep getting this error: "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request.send method expects you to provide string instead of object. Try this:

`request.send(JSON.stringify(params));`

Also, don't forget to set the correct headers on the request:

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```